# Make SQL query that rename output entries

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have table with field `category` that contains entries like the following:

```
germany_bundesliga
germany_2nd_bundesliga
england_premier_leauge
england_championship
spain_liga
spain_liga_adelante
```

and so on...

i would like to get this output:

```
gemany
england
spain
...
```

Is it possible with an SQL query?

Comment: Is this for SQL Server, MySQL, or any other databases?

Comment: MySQL... i forgot to say, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want right?

```
select distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,'_',1) from category;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a48aa/22)

Answer (score 1):

Something to think about...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('germany_2nd_bundesliga','_',1);
```

Answer (score -1):

While this is not totally pretty but in your case you can do

```
select distinct substr(category, 0, indexof(category)) from TABLE;
```

In gist

Comment: #1630 - FUNCTION substr does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: I also tried to use substring instead of substr but i get the error with indexof: #1305 - FUNCTION indexof does not exist

Comment: It did not downvote your answer, someone else did it.